# How to a drop down-down menu list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I am trying to do a dropdown menu in javascript where get all states from a function and show in the drop down menu. But the code that I have so far is showing my list wrong. Every state is next to each other instead of inside the drop down menu.

menu.js

```
export default function DropDownMenu(props){
    if(!props.states) return
    return(
        <table>
            <body>
                {props.states.map(states=>
                <select>
                    <option>{states.state}</option>
                </select>)}
            </body>
        </table>
    )
}
```

What is showing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are wrapping the `select` element within the map, try to do the following:

```
export default function DropDownMenu(props){
    if(!props.states) return
    return(
        <table>
            <body>
             // to select the value from option, just add the onChange listener
             <select onChange={(e) => { console.log(e.target.value) }}>
                {props.states.map(states=>
                  <option>{states.state}</option>
                )}
             </select>
            </body>
        </table>
    )
}
```

That way you will just render dynamically the option element.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Now can you give me hint in how do I know what was selected? What I am trying is not working.

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: I still don't understand how to use now the onChange. So like have my state and now I want to use that to show the county of that state. I have a function that gets the counties by state, so I would like to send what was selected to this function.

Comment: So please, post another question about it, it's very hard to help you from the comments.

Comment: I did another post explaining more my problem and the code that I have so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061931/how-to-make-one-dropdown-menu-dependent-on-another/72063750#72063750

Comment: I took a look and notice that you got two answers already, they didn't help you?

Comment: I think the answers have more than what I asked for. Which it makes things complicated. I was just trying to send the value to my function. Because my function is already fetching the data from my database. But I will give another look and see what I can save from there.

Comment: Hmm, I think I get it now, so for instance, when the user selects the state Alabama you want to get this value to fetch all the possible counties and show it as options?

Comment: Yeah, I want to get all counties related to Alabama from my database which my function is already doing. I just need to change from the part that shows "WHERE" in my function byCounty to the state that was selected. Anyway basically what I am trying to do is getting the states from my database showing them, after that getting the counties dependent on the state that was selected, also from my database to show. By the end I want to show a table with the values of the state and county that was selected.

Comment: I made an answer for your question, please, check if it helps you.